# pyplot.subplot vs pyplot.Subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have been reading through the [`gridspec` tutorial on matplotlib.org](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/tutorials/02_intermediate/gridspec.html), and i'm a bit confused as to the usage of the pyplot.Subplot(...) (uppercase S) function used in the "A Complex Nested GridSpec using SubplotSpec" section:

```
for i in range(16):
    inner_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(
      3, 3, subplot_spec=outer_grid[i], wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)
    a, b = int(i/4)+1, i % 4+1
    for j, (c, d) in enumerate(product(range(1, 4), repeat=2)):
        ax = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid[j])
        ax.plot(*squiggle_xy(a, b, c, d))
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        fig.add_subplot(ax)
```

It appears to be different than the [standard pyplot.subplot(...) function](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot) as it takes different arguments, but I can't find any documentation on it - i can't see it on the pyplot documentation and I can't really google it as google searches are not case sensitive. I'd like to know 
what arguments `Subplot(...)` takes, what it returns and how it differs to `subplot(...)` in general. Apologies if this is a silly question; I am still very new to matplotlib and Python in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend ignoring the existence of `Subplot` for the moment and stick to the way subplots are created in all other matplotlib examples. 
So in this case replace the line `ax = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_grid[j])` by `ax = fig.add_subplot(inner_grid[j])` and remove the line `fig.add_subplot(ax)`.

That part of the example would then look like

```
for i in range(16):
    inner_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(
      3, 3, subplot_spec=outer_grid[i], wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)
    a, b = int(i/4)+1, i % 4+1
    for j, (c, d) in enumerate(product(range(1, 4), repeat=2)):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(inner_grid[j])
        ax.plot(*squiggle_xy(a, b, c, d))
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
```

I'm not sure why they would instatiate a `Subplot` here just to add it to the figure afterwards; of course the code is valid but it somehow contradicts the pedagogy of the rest of the documentation.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. might be just me but i've been finding the matplotlib documentation in general to be somewhat... brief in places.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you really need this, I looked it up:

pyplot imports

```
from matplotlib.axes import Axes, Subplot
```

from

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py

There `Subplot` is exposed like

```
class SubplotBase(object)
...

# This is provided for backward compatibility
Subplot = subplot_class_factory()
```

`pyplot.subplot` and `pyplot.add_subplot` seem to be convenience functions that wrap this.